# Question regarding odds and odds ratios

Tags: interpretation, odds-ratio, odds

I wonder if having multiple groups (race: white, asian, black, hispanic), can I calculate odds ratios for these groups. The data are encoded as nominal variables (0,1,2 etc.)

I have a $4 \times 2$ table of race plotted by surgery (yes/no). I calculated the proportions and the odds.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Race & Yes & No \\
\hline
White & 10 & 9 \\
\hline
Asian & 5 & 3 \\
\hline
Black & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
Hispanic & ... & ... \\
\hline
\end{array}

I know that I can calculate $odds= \frac{p}{1-p}$. 
Therefore, for whites, $odds = \frac{10/19}{1-(10/19)}$

I want to calculate the odds ratio of whites to blacks getting surgery. Can I take the odds of White and divided it by odds of black, to get the odds ratio?

Then would I interpret it as:
Whites are X times more likely to receive surgery compared to blacks.
This is what I want to be able to say. Is the odds ratio the best way to say this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that the odds for white are more simply 10/9. What you describe is the standard calculation so do you have some special doubt?

Comment: @mdewey I only suppose, but probably user **Oldpineburgh** would like to emphasise that taking the ratio between odds from two different rows/races, we're trying to compare groups of different sizes. That's only my guess, but maybe that's the point of this question.

Comment: Thanks! That was my question if I was allowed to do that. I wanted to see that I was able to compare groups of different sizes and of many different groups.